# MPMoviePlayerController stops iPod music playback

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app I use MPMoviePlayerController to play a looping video on the screen and I use MPMusicPlayerController to play music. When I start playing the video, the music stops. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried setting the AudioSesion in my application delegeate but it does not seem to work.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];
```

Here's my code:

```
self.musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
MPMediaQuery* query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
[query addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"Lost" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonEqualTo]];
[query setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingAlbum];

//Pass the query to the player
[self.musicPlayer setQueueWithQuery:query];
[self.musicPlayer play];

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

// Play the movie.
[self.moviePlayer setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
```

Answer (score 2):

Mr.James. I'm also faced this problem when i play a audio file from my app. `I was worked on AVAudioPlayer to play song from my application`. When i play a song from my app if the iPod plays song was stopped and never it paused or played again. So i used below code in my app and it is working charm.

I don't know this will solve your problem. Try this and let me know your comments.

```
 musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
 if (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) 
  {
       NSLog(@"Music Playing now");
       musicPlayerPaused = YES; //BOOL
       [musicPlayer pause]; // Here am pausing the iPod Music from here..
  } 

 // Playing the message sound here using the AVAudioPlayer...
 [sendMessageSound play];
```

In **AVAudioPlayer** delegate am again resuming the iPodMusic,

```
-(void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (flag == YES) 
    {
        // IF the iPod song paused by us... we have to play it again after our Sound plays successfully...
        if (musicPlayerPaused == YES) 
        {
            musicPlayerPaused = NO;
            [musicPlayer play];
        }

    }
}
```

Please try this with and let me know your comments. Thanks. All the best.